# Overwrite max-width with new property

Tags: html, css

You'll see in this code we have a tree of random code and child image. The child image will always follow the parents max-width property for images, even if you use a custom class. Is there anyway to get by this for the class used?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41tyamsz/1/)**

**[Actual use of code](http://www.beeskneesfx.com/showthread.php?384-Ignore-this&p=1929#post1929)**

**Note** this is on vbulletin using so many CSS overrides it's ridiculous. The new CSS is in the vbulletin custom css file "additional.css"

**Additionally note** that the hover effect **does** constrain to 120px, however the normal class out of over does not.

**CODE**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>
        <div>
            <div class="something">
               <img src="http://shadowness.com/file/item9/314049/image.jpg" class="thumbbbimg" />
            </div>
         </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.thumbbbimg {
    max-width: 120px;
}
```

**Actual CSS**

```
/* Thumb BBCode CSS */
    .content img.thumbbbimg {
        width: 120px;
        max-width: 120px;
        max-height: 120px;
        opacity: 75;
        margin: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
        filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
        filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content img.thumbbbimg:hover {
        width: 120px;
        max-width: 120px;
        max-height: 120px;
        opacity: 100;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
        filter: gray;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0); 
  }
```

Comment: `img.thumbbbimg` - http://jsfiddle.net/o33y6bre/

Comment: so you want the image to have a width of 120px?

Comment: Yes. And @MaryMelody I already have tried that. It does not work on the forums within hundreds of sub-childs.

Comment: The second rule is less specific than the first, hence it's is being overruled by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.content img :not(.thumbbimg) {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .thumbbbimg {
        max-width: 120px; 
    }
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/41tyamsz/2/

using `:not` will apply the rule to elements except specified ones.

Comment: This made the image display at 100% of it's actual dimensions, rather then 100% of the content contains. Hmm.

Comment: @user3701746 this is not true the image will display @ 120 px as long as the class is applied , have you checked my fiddle ?

Comment: @user3701746 i inspected it the image doesnt have the class thumbbimg !! weird !

Comment: @user3701746 are you sure that you defined the class in the right file ? please give a link to the css file where you defined thumbbimg.

Comment: @user3701746 this is because the image doesnt inherit the class , it is not listed in the inspected values.

Comment: @user3701746 add the thumbbimg style to the same file that has :not() rule.

Comment: Yes it's there located here: http://www.beeskneesfx.com/css.php?styleid=4&langid=1&d=1413166016&td=ltr&sheet=additional.css

Comment: Got it! That suggestion did it. Too many overwrites in this mess.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by replace the `.thumbbbimg` with `img.thumbbbimg` like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0bs5axLx/)**

```css
.content img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
img.thumbbbimg {
    max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>
        <div>
            <div class="something">
                <img src="http://shadowness.com/file/item9/314049/image.jpg" class="thumbbbimg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: 1+ You should explain that this is a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue though.

Comment: If you tried this and it didn't help, then you haven't posted a complete code example.

Comment: Would you like some 40 vbulletin CSS files? lol Read the additional notes.

Comment: @MaryMelody I have already tried that as well with `.postbody .thumbbbimg`

Comment: The thumbnail code can be seen here (same image) http://www.beeskneesfx.com/showthread.php?384-Ignore-this&p=1929#post1929

Answer (score -1):

Don't make a habit of this but you could override with a !important like so

```
.thumbbbimg {
    max-width: 120px !important;
```

}

Comment: using !important is not recommended , you can try your solution though and check if it works.